# Getting NULL Deserializing JSON string using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#

Hi I having following JSON but while Using Deserialize method getting NULL in nested Member here is the sample JSON and corresponding Class object:

```
{
   "status": "success",
    "Info": [
      {
       "Name": "1099589",
       "version": "Current Version",
       "MoreDetails": [
        {

          "Name": "1099589",
          "state": "IN"

        },
        {
          "Name": "1099768",
          "state": "OUT"

        }

      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "1099768",
      "version": "2019"
    }
  ],
  "errorCode": "",
  "message": ""
}
```

Class :

```
  public class MoreDetail
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
    }

    public class Info
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
        public IList<MoreDetail> MoreDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public IList<Info> Info { get; set; }
        public string errorCode { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
    }
```

While I am using

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Example ex = new OfferingPayload();
ex = js.Deserialize<Example> (jsonstring);
```

I am able to see Example object having Info data as list but MoreDetails member of Info Class is coming NULL.

Can someone suggest what I am missing here ?

Comment: your JSON is invalid. you have two trailing commas: `"state": "IN",` and `"state": "OUT",`  - next time, validate your data first, for example with https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: https://quicktype.io/csharp/, _Edit-Paste Special-Paste Json as Classes_ in Visual Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because your second "Info" object doesnt have "MoreDetails" property.

```
{
  "Name": "1099768",
  "version": "2019"
}
```

To make it works you can add an empty "MoreDetails" property to your json.

```
{
  "Name": "1099768",
  "version": "2019",
  "MoreDetails": []
}
```

Or you can configure your serializer to handle this property as optional. Then it will works fine even if it missing in your json.

Comment: Created similar JSON string with "MoreDetails" :[ ] empty option , But Still I see NULL .

Comment: I pasted code that I use to check it - [https://www.paste.org/105177](https://www.paste.org/105177). It works fine. I use .Net Framework 4.7.2 and JavascriptSerializer from System.Web.Script.Serialization namespace. Maybe you take some errors in your json, or maybe you have configuration for your serializer somewhere that limits max json depth

Comment: Thnx ! Without empty "MoreDeatils [] it just worked , Everything was fine still I didn't see any issue what I did just re-generated the CLASSES Again , it worked .,